# What are good JavaScript OOP resources?

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

JavaScript is a lightweight and powerful language, but it's often misunderstood and hard to learn (especially about its object oriented programming).

What are the good materials (blogs, screencasts and books) to learn JavaScript OOP? The topics can be anything, but let's not include browsers, AJAX and libraries for now.

Also how did you learn the functional programming, closure, object, inheritance and design patterns in JavaScript? Personally I would like to see more code examples because some of the books I mentioned above keep the example minimal.

*(EDIT: As this post is now community effort, please **help maintain and develop the following list of resources**!)*

**Books**

- [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) by Douglas Crockfond, This is the book recommended by most of Javascripters on Stack overflow. I observed, People have advanced their skills in java script with this book. Visit his website: [crockford.com](http://www.crockford.com/) for more information.
- [Object-Oriented JavaScript: Create scalable, reusable high-quality JavaScript applications and libraries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194141) by Stoyan Stefanov, goes through many OOP topics such as Objects, Prototype, Inheritance and some patterns.
- [Pro JavaScript Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059908X), by Ross Harmess and Dustin Diaz, discuss application of famous design patterns in JavaScript.

**Videos**

- ["Advanced JavaScript" videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwYPG6vreJg) by Douglas Crockford. Many other interesting videos are available at [Yahoo! Developer Network](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/).
- [The Definitive Guide to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMfcsYzj-9M) by James Shore (July 2013).

**On Stack Overflow**

- [A Stack Overflow discussion on JavaScript closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795549/difference-between-classjava-and-closurejavascript)
- [A Stack Overflow discussion on What exactly does “closure” refer to in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801957/what-exactly-does-closure-refer-to-in-javascript)
- [A Stack Overflow discussion on Prototypal vs Functional OOP in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557386/prototypal-vs-functional-oop-in-javascript)

**Others**

- [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) - Mozilla Dev
- [JavaScript Closures for Dummies](http://web.archive.org/web/20080209105120/http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies)
- [JavaScript Closures](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html)
- [JavaScript Closures 101](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml)
- [Private Members in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) by Douglas Crockfond
- [Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) by by Douglas Crockfond
- [Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) by by Douglas Crockfond
- [JavaScript, time to grok closures](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/23/javascript-time-to-grok-closures.aspx)
- [Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: Shouldn't this be a community wiki?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see great code examples of Javascript in mainstream libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com). I've learned a lot just reading it's source code. There's nothing better than reading sources that are working in millions of websites and are concerned about best practices.

Comment: jQuery is more functional than OOP, no?  But there are good OOP frameworks to look at (Ext, Dojo, YUI) and I would also recommend doing so.  No one better to learn from than those actually making it work in today's browsers.

Comment: There are many libraries I know. Is it possible to tell which library prefers which strategy (i.e., Crockford defines three a) Psudoclassical, Protypal and Functional OOP)?

Answer (score 3):

In the same vein as [The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742), Douglas Crockford's [website](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/) has many good articles on JavaScript and OOP, such as [Prototypal Inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html), C[lassical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html), etc.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous references to Crockford's work, I recommend you read this perspective on the contrast of Functional vs. Classical inheritance patterns in JS:

[Inheritance Patterns in JavaScript by Michael Bolin](http://bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php)

Answer (score 1):

The recent [Crockford on JavaScript](http://yuiblog.com/crockford/) video talks are worth watching - Act III: Function the Ultimate covers OOP in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this blog post to be the most clear explanation of prototypes: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/

I have written a blog series on object orientation in JavaScript. You can access it here: https://rahuldotout.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/javascript-a-different-beast-part-7-inheritance-without-classes/

Answer (score 0):

Most of the resources you can get surfing on the internet. You can see the links googling on google. With the oops javascript code, there is no need for the developers to rewrite the code instead they can create small blocks of code. I' m listing down the resources of which I'm aware of -

https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-resources-for-JavaScript-OOP

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/topics/javascript-oop

https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/