# JavaScript OOP Best Practices: construct & extend

Tags: javascript, oop, optimization

I am working to optimize my practices in JS but yet I could not construct a perfect benchmark to answer me the following questions.

**What is the best structure of a JS "Class"?**

I have tried each of the following without any obvious performance peak.

```
(function() { // Scope! as a JS function
    //0.example
    var A = new function() {
            this.x = 0; // Will be constructed on runtime initiation
            A.prototype.afunc = function() {
                // do something
                return this;
            };
        };

    //1.example
    var B = new function() {
            var x = 0;
            B.prototype.bfunc = function() {
                // do something
                return this;
            };
        };

    //2.example
    var C = new function() {
            var x = 0;
            this.cfunc = function() {
                // do something
                return this;
            };
        };

    //3.example
    function D() { // old fashion way
        var x = 0;

        function dfunc() {
            // do something
            return this;
        };
    };

    //4.example
    var E = { // Interface style, but works perfect as an Enum style but I can't extend it
        x: 0,
        efunc: function() {
            // do something
            return this;
        }
    };
})();
```

But so far I have notice that 0-2 examples have the best capabilities to be extended and can adapt better OOP rules.

**Which of the following can serve as Class constructor and why?**

This is one of my major issues. I can't clearly figure the best structure for a class constructor. The problems gets worse when it comes to extend a class ( and use it as a super/parent constructor )

The following code is my example of use. My experience has show me the 6th(5) example is the best to use when it comes to flexibility inside the "Class". But the inheritance is still tricky.

```
    //5.example
var F = new function(a, b, c) {
        var x = 0;

        F.prototype.init = function(a, b, c) {
            // do something
            return this;
        };
        // During runtime will compute & initilize
        return this.init(a, b, c);
    };

//6.example
function G(a, b, c) {
    var x;
    var y;

    function init() {
        x = a;
        y = b + c;
        return this;
    };
    return this.init();
};

//7.example
var H = new function(a, b, c) {
        var instance = { // Runtime Construction
            x: a,
            y: b + c,
        };
        // do something
        return init;
    };
```

**Is it possible to achieve extension and inheritance as it happens in any common OOP language?**

I have tried various techniques but none have convince me to be the optimal.

```
//8.example
var I = new F.prototype;
I.prototype.ifunc() {
    // do something
    return this;
}

//9.example
var J = new G(0,1,2);
J.jfunc() {
    // do something
    return this;
}
```

So to sum up, What is the best practice to write OO JS? and how can you benchmark it to reject others?

Comment: Never set prototype properties from inside your constructor !!!1 This leads to a horrible scope mess with local variables.

Comment: I am using prototype only to register functions, I've not yet reach a mess with that technique, yet it is annoying. thx!

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why you keep declaring `foo = new function () {}`. That's the opposite of what is good.

Comment: I don't understand what the actual question is. Are these three questions? Also, what exactly do you want to benchmark? Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908443/what-are-good-javascript-oop-resources

Comment: You should look into John Resig's Simple Inheritance - he's embarking on quite the same journey as you: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Comment: That's The problem I've came across, I can't rely on frameworks just to make an easier extension and achieve Inheritance. There must be a way to make it optimal. @zzzBov I use `foo = new function () {}` to implement an object-like form. @Felix-kling I don't actually seek for design patterns in this post rather than the optimal way to achieve a good structure in JS.