# Valums Ajax file Upload handle the up. file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

Yes so I am using this, valums ajax fileupload:
http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

With these settings:

```
function createUploader(){            
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
        action: 'photo.php?mode=upload',
        debug: true
    });           
}
```

Not on photo.php?mode=upload, I tried to handle the file that are being uploaded, by

```
if(isset($_FILES['qqfile'])){
$filename = $_FILES['qqfile']['name'];
$imageSizeInfo = getimagesize($filename);
}
```

It doesnt execute this, no $_FILES isset.. ? Have i forgotten anything to add in the script settings? And i tried to remove the if statement, then it just says getimagesize error needs parameter cannot be empty.

Comment: Why are you testing for `ppfile`, but retrieving `qqfile`?  Do a `print_r($_FILES);` to see what gets uploaded

Comment: @pekka Sorry a typo, i meant qqfile in the isset too.. I did print_r($_FILES) before the if and got: Array() .. its empty

Answer (score 2):

Valums upload script ([latest version](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)) sends file information by ajax (xhr stream) when using Firefox, Chrome or Safari).  However IE6/7/8/9 does not support it and falls back to iframe support which properly sets the $_FILES array.

If you only want to use the super global $_FILES array you can use the older version of [Valums script](https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload) and it will perform the same across all browsers.

Comment: So if i understood this correctly in IE it do perform the $_FILES array, and the newer (ff, chrome, safari) (i used ff trying this) are using the "xhr stream" ? how can i handle this xhr stream then in the server side/php..?

Comment: That's correct.  From the zip file downloaded from the site, look at the /server/php.php file.  In particular the qqUploadedFileXhr class near the top.  The save() method takes the stream and saves it to a temp file.  The qqFileUploader class further down decides which upload handler class to use (either Xhr or Form).

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 kind of methods for upload in valums script, `qqUploadedFileXhr` and `qqUploadedFileForm`. If you use example script, then you use a default one : `qqUploadedFileXhr`.

so, to get the files info you can use : `$file_name = $_GET['qqfile']`; 
that's it, just filename only.

but, if use the 'qqUploadedFileForm', you can get the files info :

- `$_FILES['qqfile']['name']` for filename
- `$_FILES['qqfile']['size']` for size etc